# In the Java framework why is there no .write overload in the BufferedWriter class which accepts a byte array?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I'm interested in writing arrays of bytes to disk using [BufferedWriter.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).  But that method wants an array of characters.  I'll have to convert the byte[] to char[].  Easy right?  Well my first try in Clojure failed to convert the bytes to chars.  Thus I started wondering why the BufferedWriter.write() method is so picky about wanting char[].
Note:  OuputStream has a [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method which takes byte[].  So my question is about the framework design choice for wanting char[] in BufferedWrite.write().

Comment: All Writer's write chars, period. So you shouldn't try to use a Writer of any sort to write out byte[]. Instead use an OutputStream if you want to stream byte[]. Your question is like someone complaining that their screwdriver is not working well as a hammer, when the real problem isn't that the tool doesn't work well but rather that they're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: So what you are saying is that given the two English words "Write" and "Stream" which both have connotations here of writing to disk that a newbie should automatically know which of those two tools works with bytes[] and all reasons why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) is a kind of [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html), and `Writer` is meant for writing characters.  To output raw bytes, you want to use some type of [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) — in this case, a [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html).

(The bridge between `OutputStream` and `Writer` is the [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) class.  It's a `Writer` that takes characters, encodes them into bytes using a scheme such as UTF-8, and feeds the resulting bytes to an `OutputStream`.)

Comment: Ahhh how did I miss BufferedOutputStream?  I swear I looked for it... missed it!  Thanks.  I'll close this before the millions of java progs storm my gates.

Answer (score 1):

It's right in the first line of the class Javadoc:

> Write text to a character-output stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient writing of single characters, arrays, and strings.

Classes which implement `Writer` are designed for text output, not arbitrary binary data. Look into other buffered streams such as [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)

Comment: So, in general, buffering functionality is only for text?

Comment: See my edit -- you just need to use a different stream class, one designed for binary data.

Comment: @fooledbyprimes: No! there are BufferedOutputStreams.